# Accessing multiple Gmail accounts via one .NET5 microservice (application)

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I've read some related questions, but they are not 100% related, as the requirements vary a bit.

I have a .NET5 web application, some kind of custom CRM for the company I work in.
We have multiple users (employees, my colleagues), which can create quotations, etc.
Also, they can send these quotations to customers. Every user has its email account name attached to it.

The current way this application works is that I've created and enabled Gmail API *for each email account*, and authorized it, *by myself*, manually.

The problem is that every time we need to add a new user (new employee for instance) - I need to enable Gmail API of his email account (company's one, but it doesn't matter), add the credential file and token manually to the server, authenticate it, and only then - the application can use the email.

I know that there are many sites (like Monday, etc) - that have automations and integrations with Gmail, and any time I want some integration - I get notified with the OAuth screen, and approve it. I want the same thing in my application.

I understand that I have to create some kind on "Gmail global credential", which will be "added" with account tokens or something like that (every app user will oauth and allow access)?
Just can't find the correct documentation for it.

My backend is written in Blazor Server, .NET5.

I would appreciate if one could explain the main stages of this procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: _"every time we need to add a new user  ... enable Gmail API ... add the credential file and token manually to the server, authenticate it"_ you're trying to do machine-to-machine communication, which necessitates those credentials. But if you switch to using OAuth & let users of your application login with their credentials, and approve the scopes (Gmail: r + w) then you can use the token returned by Google in your app to send mails on their behalf.

Comment: I don't understand `I've created and enabled Gmail API for each email account, and authorized it, by myself, manually`. APIs are usually enabled for a project, not for an account https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en. Can you provide more details on how you are doing this? Also, do you want users to see the OAuth consent screen or not? If you don't want user interaction, I'd suggest using [a service account with domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) for this. Can you clarify this a bit more?

Comment: Okay Iamblichus, I'd like more info if you care to furnish it.  Let's say you've enabled Gmail API for your project (which I had to do to allow Google registration).  How would you send an e-mail from the server from a specific user?

Comment: Just follow the guide in the documentation I mentioned. The exact code would depend on the language you're using (the impersonated account has to be specified in a specific parameter). And after impersonating, you'd call [send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) the same way you would do usually. If you ask something more specific, I'll be glad to respond.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How is it possible to prompt users to OAuth themselves? I have a micro-service that is used to send emails. Is it even possible?